# Remove horizontal scroll in mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have developed a website. It looks fine when i am resizing the browser window on my laptop but when I opened it in mobile browser, it set a horizontal scroll which makes it look weird.Any help is highly appreciated.
Link : https://dcheroes.uphero.com

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help you in **your code**. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read through the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to ask a question that is acceptable in the forum. Also how about giving us something to work with? Like the code or your website URL? Without it we can only agree its side scrolling and only you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop in responsive you must need to use media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: ** px) and (min-width: **px) {
}
```

And whenever you use `width` to outermost elements replace with it `max-width`. For more information read following articles

[Max-width MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

[Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score -1):

This is called creating a *responsive* design. Creating responsive designs requires a whole lot more knowledge of HTML/CSS.

Learn about responsive designs and how to create them here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Have you thought about using Bootstrap, this can make creating responsive designs much easier as they've done much of the work for you already.

Learn about Bootstrap and how to use it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

**EDIT:** My apologies, it looks like you're already using Bootstrap. But barely using it IE: you're not using `<div class="container">` or `div class="row"`or classes such as `col-md-6`. I highly recommend if you're going to use Bootstrap you ensure you keep using their design language throughout.